# 2021 version of the "Is `<a>` inside of a `<button>` (officially) allowed?" question

Tags: html, forms, button

I'm not good at finding and understanding the official w3c specs, so bear over with me.

All I want to know is whether or not I can officially, in 2021, use an interactive (clickable with href="") anchor tag inside of a HTML `<button>` element:

```html
<button>
  <a href="https://...">Click Here!</a>
</button>
```

Earlier articles state that only *phrasing content* is allowed, and `<a>` is according to MDN considered phrasing content only if it doesn't contain an interactive link (href=""). This article contains that type of information: https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

[MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) the same, that only phrasing content without interactivity allowed.

Others think [wrapping the button](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-add-a-link-to-button-in-HTML) in an anchor tag is the way to go (August 2021 (!)).

As far as I can understand, the only allowed option, is to wrap the button in a form, if I want to make the button send the user to another URL (unless I want to use a JS click event):

```html
<form action="https://..." method="GET">
  <button>Click Here!</button>
</form>
```

Any tips on authoritative sources for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Wrapping an anchor in a button

You cannot include an anchor with `href` in a `button`, because the current [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) prescribes the following content model:

> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant

where [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2t) includes *"`<a>`  (if the `href` attribute is present)"*

---

#### Wrapping a button in an anchor

You cannot include a `button` in an anchor because the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) dictates that

> [...] there must be no interactive content [...]

where [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2t) includes *"`<button>`"*

---

So the remaining options that I can identify are:

- Style your `button` as an anchor, or your anchor as a `button`
- Use the `button`'s `click` event handler
- Wrap the `button` in a `form`
- Do whatever you like and hope that the browsers you need to support are permissive enough to forgive your transgressions

Comment: Great, very clear answer, thanks. How do you go about finding out which W3C spec is the most recent? I noticed the one you linked to is marked 14 December 2017
superseded 28 January 2021 and I'm not sure what superseded means.

Comment: I updated with links to the current [living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/). For cases as clear-cut as this one though, it doesn't matter all that much as the spec doesn't materially change.